# Initiating MFC class from another dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have made an MFC application (VS2010) - exe.I then changed it to be dll (in project properties).

Some class CmyClass is inheriting CWinApp in my MFC dll.

From the other DLL (standard win32 DLL) I want to create the class and call it as it made by running the MFC as application (EXE).

I have tried to declare the CmyClass with DLLEXPORT, in my win32 DLL I Load the MFC dll dynamically and performing AfxWinInit with the hinstance of the MFC dll.
I have tried than to:

1. Create (CmyClass * a= new CmyClass()), wanted to call InitApplication(), InitInstance() and Run()
2. Call AfxGetApp() -> retrieving NULL pointer.

All without success. What Am I doing wrong?

10x,
Guy

EDIT:

I need the other way around though... I have created MFC App since it's wizard is wider and richer then the MFC Dll one. I want to consume this Dll the same manner I will consume the App (Exe). I found that from the consuming Dll it is sufficient just to LoadLibrary(MFCDll) to start the MFC Initialization (AfxWinInit is called and CMyClass->InitInstance is being called as well, but fails afterwards with exceptions.

Comment: Rather than changing a app into an exe it's easier to start with a template app and move the code into it.

Comment: I need the other way around though....

Comment: Don't know if it would help or not but try these:

1) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/beginnerdll.aspx
2) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/RegDLL.aspx